# How can I resolve a problem with IP type inferences, getting "cannot infer type for type `{integer}`"?

Tags: rust, ip, type-inference

I keep getting warnings like this,

```
error[E0698]: type inside `async fn` body must be known in this context
  --> src/http.rs:38:10
   |
38 |         .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030))
   |                ^^^ cannot infer type for type `{integer}`
```

For every octet in the IP address. How can I resolve this problem.

Comment: Can you provide some more context, i.e. where is `run()` defined & what is its signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the signature of `run()` it's not possible to tell why the type inference fails, but you can explicitly do conversion and skirt the type inference entirely which will certainly work with `run(addr)`.

```rust
use std::net;

// `SocketAddr` via `From` with (ip,port) tuple
let addr: net::SocketAddr = net::SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030));

// `SocketAddr` from string
let addr: net::SocketAddr = "127.0.0.1:3030".parse().unwrap();
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1cf9ad1abb0fd701aca5374543c04809)

Comment: I went ahead and merged my answer which I know works, with your answer which I know also would have worked, just because I don't like to self-answer things when there is another equally good contribution. =) thanks.